# java split string from file, java.util.NoSuchElementException error

Tags: java

I have a file named lol.txt containing text as following:

```
10000002$11-beta-hydroxylase deficiency$$10010331$$$$$$$$
10000005$17 ketosteroids urine$$10022891$$$$$$$$
10000007$17 ketosteroids urine decreased$$10022891$$$$$$$$
10000009$17 ketosteroids urine increased$$10022891$$$$$$$$
10000011$17 ketosteroids urine normal$$10022891$$$$$$$$
10000013$17,20-desmolase deficiency$$10010331$$$$$$$$
```

Im writing a java program that will extract the file content. The expected output is as follows:

```
beta-hydroxylase deficiency
ketosteroids urine
ketosteroids urine decreased
.
.
```

My code:

```
public class TextSplitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("lol.txt"));
        read.useDelimiter("$");
        String var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11;
        while (read.hasNext())
        {
            var1 = read.next();
            var2 = read.next();
            var3 = read.next();
            var4 = read.next();
            var5 = read.next();
            var6 = read.next();
            var7 = read.next();
            var8 = read.next();
            var9 = read.next();
            var10 = read.next();
            var11 = read.next();
            System.out.println("" + var2);
        }
        read.close();
    }
}
```

The error was:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: First of all read more about arrays and loops because your code doesn't look good.

Answer (score 2):

The method accepts a regex, and not a String. `$` has a special meaning in regex, you should quote it to treat it as the *String* "$", you have two options:

- Escaping the special characters with `\` (in Java `\` is represented as `\\`):

  `read.useDelimiter("\\$");`
- Use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) that does this for you:

  `read.useDelimiter(Pattern.quote("$"));`

I highly recommend you to read about loops and Java, it'll make your life easier. Go through the [basic tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to read the input line-by-line and then parse lines (for example, using [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)). Also store the result to the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), not to individual variables:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while(read.hasNext()) {
    results.add(read.nextLine().split("\\$", 3)[1]);
}
System.out.println(results);
```

Here we split every input row into pieces separated by `'$'` and take the piece #1 (numbering starts from zero).

If you don't want to store results, just to print them to standard output, use

```
while(read.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(read.nextLine().split("\\$", 3)[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to escape your `$` character, because [delimiter](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/SettingDelimitersforScanner.htm) in scan accepts regexp.
And secondly use list instead of list of variables, its's more flexible.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("lol.txt"));
        read.useDelimiter("//$"); 

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>(); // JDK7++
        while (read.hasNext())
        {
            results.add(read.next());
        }
        read.close();
    }
```

Second benefit og using lists is that you will scan all elements, with your approach you will get an exception if number of elements is lover than number of variables.